# Add a grid column showing values

Tags: magento-1.7, grid, model

I've added some fields in a form using an array as source:

```
 $addInternalInformation->addField(
        'return_type', 'select',
        array(
            'name'  => 'return_type',
            'label' => $this->__('Return type'),
            'values' => Mage::getModel('modulename/source_returntype')->toOptionArray()
        )
    );
```

Now I'd like to show that values in the grid instead of the index, should I use a Render Class or there is a simpler method?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved creating a _toOption() function to use inside the addColumn grid method:

```
$this->addColumn(
            'return_type',
            array(
                'header'  => 'return_type',
                'index' => 'return_type',
                'type' => 'options',
                'options' => $this->_toOptions(Mage::getModel('modulename/source_returntype')->toOptionArray())

            )
        );

protected function _toOptions($optArray){
        $options=array();
        foreach ($optArray as $option){
            $options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];

    }
```

Comment: The other solution is create the function toArray in Mage::getModel('modulename/source_returntype') and process data with format.